# I am trying to animate a searchbar that slide open when click while the navbar disappear vice verse

Tags: javascript, html, css, searchbar

My Problem now is that when I click to remove the class and have  the search bar collapse while the navbar re-appear, the searchbar while collapsing moves downward because the re--appearing navbar quickly takes up its place in the header before the searchBar finish collasping, even though i added transition to both animation and the navbar with to 0 and transition back slowly so that the searchbar have enough time to collapse while maintaining its position in the layout.

Obviously I am nit doing it correctly could somebody please help me achieve my goal?
Thanks,

Html

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('.btn'),
  searchBar = document.querySelector('.searchBar'),
  searchContainer = document.querySelector('.search-container'),
  searchInput = document.querySelector('.search-input'),
  login = document.querySelector('.login'),
  inputContiainer = document.querySelector('.input-container'),
  navBar = document.querySelector('.navBar');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if(classie.hasClass(searchContainer,'open') &&
    classie.hasClass(searchBar,'elongate') &&
    classie.hasClass(navBar,'hide')){
    classie.removeClass(searchContainer,'open');
    classie.removeClass(searchBar,'elongate');
    classie.removeClass(navBar,'hide');
  }else{
    classie.addClass(navBar,'hide');
    classie.addClass(searchContainer,'open');
    classie.addClass(searchBar,'elongate');
  }
})
```

```css
       navBar {
               float: left;
               width: auto;
               margin-left: 8.333333333333333%;
               padding-top: 25px;
               transition: width 0.68s ease-in-out;
             }
           .nav {
               display: flex;
               list-style: none;
           }
           .nav a {
                text-decoration: none;
                display: block;
                padding: 8px 16px;
                font-size: 16px;
            }
            .searchBar {
                float: right;
                padding-right: 25px;
                padding-top: 16px;
                width: 40px;
                transition: width 0.68s ease-in-out;
            }
           .open {
                transition: width 0.68s ease-in;
                width: 100%;
            }
           .navBar.hide {
                transition: width 0.68s ease-in-out;
                width: 0;
            }
            .navBar.hide ul {
                display: none;
             }
             .elongate {
                 transition: width 0.68s ease-in-out;
                 width: 43%;
              }
```

```html
<div class="navBar">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="login">
                <span class="fa fa-user"></span>
            </a>
            <div class="searchBar">
                <div class="search-container">
                    <form>
                        <label class="btn">
                            <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
                        </label>
                       <div class="input-container">
                          <input type="search" placeholder="Enter Keyword" class="search-input"> 
                       </div> 
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

For the classie stuffs is just a min-library for adding, removing, and toggling class.

Comment: First of, you are missing a `.` before `navBar` in your css. Otherwise try adding  `transition-delay: 0.68s;` to `.navBar`

Answer (score 0):

After long hard brainstorming especially as my questions was uncharacteristically ignored for the most part, i have finally find out the solution to my problem, the reason for the searchbar wraping unto a newline when returning back was that the navbar width was initially set auto, and somehow the value auto was unable to have the transition delay,

Giving the navBar a fixed width actually produced the desired result.

```
  .navBar {
      float: left;
      width: 40%;/* as opposed to auto, which didn't transition smoothly*/
      margin-left: 8.333333333333333%;
      padding-top: 25px;
      transition: width 0.68s ease-in-out;
```

}